# hide querystring with url rewrite

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, query-string

I have a querystring like: `www.example.com/items/report.asp?id=2&no=12&iq=200&td=1`

How would i hide the query string part using url rewrite?

Output should be like: `www.example.com/items/report.asp`

```
<rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=([0-9]+)" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="&amp;no=([0-9]+)" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="&amp;iq=([0-9]+)" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="&amp;td=([0-9]+)" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/items/report.asp" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/items/report.asp" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: I'm not sure i've understood what you're asking. Do you want to go to `/items/report.asp` and see the same content as `/items/report.asp?id=2&no=12&iq=200&td=1` ? In that case, you need to understand that query parameters need to be static (if they're dynamic, you can't use url-rewriting here for this)

Comment: @Justin yes i need the exact content as /items/report.asp?id=2&no=12&iq=200&td=1 and the parameters are dynamic.

Comment: As i said, if your parameters are dynamic, you can't use url rewriting here. You need something to let the server know what "id" and "no" and "iq" and "td" you need. It's not possible with only the url `/items/report.asp`